# Merging column values into one column without comma on python (without pandas)

Tags: python, csv, merge

Question on how to merge different column values into out without comma on python...

My task as like this.

A big csv file data has following rows

```
s,0,6,8,9,2,-,3,6,2,8,7,1,0,n,.,c,s,v
s,0,5,9,6,0,-,3,6,7,0,1,6,0,n,.,c,s,v
s,1,9,0,5,5,-,3,6,1,5,5,8,6,n,.,c,s,v
s,2,8,0,7,9,-,3,2,5,1,8,2,7,n,.,c,s,v
s,0,0,5,6,5,-,3,3,4,0,5,7,0,n,.,c,s,v
s,3,0,3,4,8,-,3,5,9,1,2,2,6,n,.,c,s,v
s,0,3,8,8,9,-,3,7,3,1,0,2,5,n,.,c,s,v
```

I want to make this look like follow:

```
06892
05960
19055
28079
00565
30348
03889
```

I attempted following code without success.

```
import csv, os

with open ('/Desktop/case.csv','r') as h:
    reader = csv.reader(h)
    for row in reader:
        k = row[1:6]
        print(k)
```

When I did this, following results come up.

```
0,6,8,9,2
0,5,9,6,0
1,9,0,5,5
2,8,0,7,9
0,0,5,6,5
3,0,3,4,8
0,3,8,8,9
```

How to make this look like my desired output, i.e. without commas?

Comment: Use 'join'... `''.join(k)`

Comment: Thank you Scott.. actually I have just used ' '.join(k) with following code..  however I got the exact same results..

Comment: Is `k` a string? You probably have to do `''.join(k.split(","))`

Comment: Thank you Pault, but it's a list, and I get this message. AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Answer (score 1):

Use `join`:

```
from io import StringIO
import csv
txtfile = StringIO("""s,0,6,8,9,2,-,3,6,2,8,7,1,0,n,.,c,s,v
s,0,5,9,6,0,-,3,6,7,0,1,6,0,n,.,c,s,v
s,1,9,0,5,5,-,3,6,1,5,5,8,6,n,.,c,s,v
s,2,8,0,7,9,-,3,2,5,1,8,2,7,n,.,c,s,v
s,0,0,5,6,5,-,3,3,4,0,5,7,0,n,.,c,s,v
s,3,0,3,4,8,-,3,5,9,1,2,2,6,n,.,c,s,v
s,0,3,8,8,9,-,3,7,3,1,0,2,5,n,.,c,s,v""")

reader = csv.reader(txtfile) 
for row in reader: 
        k = row[1:6] 
        print(''.join(k))
```

Output:

```
06892
05960
19055
28079
00565
30348
03889
```

Comment: Thank you very much. What about if input file is csv instead of txt? It seems I have to covert the csv into txt first?

Comment: I just did this to show you how it can be done via this example, you you can do you're same csv.reader as you're doing before.

Comment: I am quite new to this world, so my understanding on this is... with open ('/Desktop/case.csv','r') as h:
    reader = csv.reader(h)
    for row in reader:
        k = row[1:6]
        k = k.split(",")
        print(''.join(k)) would work?  I tried, but     k = k.split(",")
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'  was the returned error.

Comment: Yes.  I think so.

Comment: Also, I tried to upvote your answer, but my reputation is very low (<15) and not allowing to upvote yet. But I really appreciate your answer again...

Comment: You should be able to accept click checkmark.   If this works for you.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top